# android:textIsSelectable no WebView

Tags: android, webview

Estou criando um app, e eu queria deixar `hide` a opção de selecionar o o texto e copiar.

Sabe quando a gente da `focus` em cima do texto e aparece aquela opção de copiar ou compartilhar o texto, eu queria remover isso.

WebView;

```
<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webView_des"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    />
```

Código que pega o `body` em forma de `string`;

```
String mimeType = "text/html; charset=UTF-8";
            String encoding = "utf-8";
            String htmlText = allArrayNewsDes[position];

            String text = "<html><head>"
                    + "<style type=\"text/css\">body{color: #525252;}"
                    + "</style></head>"
                    + "<body>"                          
                    +  htmlText
                    + "</body></html>";

            webnewsdes.loadData(text, mimeType, encoding);
```

Já tentei de tudo mas sem sucesso.

Tipo isso aqui, eu quero remover do WebView;

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adicione um **OnLongClickListener** à WebView e faça o método `onLongClick()` retornar `true`.

```
webnewsdes.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        return true;
    }
});
```

Comment: Muito obrigado :), me salvou!